# Why isn't my Active Directory changes updating in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: active-directory

I notice today when someone was trying to give a user permission to a folder on their site.  The user that they were trying to add was not showing up.  But when I went to look in AD I saw the user.  How do I go about fixing this issue.

Comment: do you have the user profile synchronization service on and syncing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sync the user profile service, jump into central admin and run the timer job, or double check the status in the service applications manager, "manage profile service".

Comment: ok I will look into this now, thank you.  Will update once I try this out.

Comment: No problem, fingers crossed it's that simple. If not, it might require a bit more troubleshooting!